# efficient way to check every value in a 2d python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of values, a list of x-coordinates, and a list of y-coordinates. the x-coordinates increase left-to-right and the y-coordinates increase top-to-bottom.

For example:

```
a = np.random.random((3, 3))
a[0][1] = 9.0
a[0][2] = 9.0
a[1][1] = 9.0
a[1][2] = 9.0
xs = list(range(1112, 1115))
ys = list(range(1109, 1112))
```

Output:

```
[[0.48148651 9.         9.        ]
 [0.09030393 9.         9.        ]
 [0.79271224 0.83413552 0.29724989]]

[1112, 1113, 1114]

[1109, 1110, 1111]
```

I want to remove the values from the 2D array that are greater than 1. I also want to combine the lists `xs` and `ys` to get a list of all the coordinate pairs for points that are kept.

In this example I want to remove `a[0][1], a[0][2], a[1][1], a[1][2]` and I want the list of coordinate pairs to be

```
[[1112, 1109], [1112,1110], [1112, 1111], [1113, 1111], [1114, 1111]]
```

I have been able to accomplish this using a double `for` loop and `if` statements:

```
a_values = []
point_pairs = []
for i in range(0, a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, a.shape[1]):
        if (a[i][j] < 1):
            a_values.append(a[i][j])
            point_pairs.append([xs[j], ys[i]])
print(a_values)
print(point_pairs)
```

Output:

```
[0.48148650831317796, 0.09030392566133771, 0.7927122386213029, 0.8341355206494774, 0.2972498933037804]
[[1112, 1109], [1112, 1110], [1112, 1111], [1113, 1111], [1114, 1111]]
```

What is a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to get the indices of the elements you removed:

```
mask = a < 1
i, j = np.nonzero(mask)
```

The fancy indices `i` and `j` can be used to get the elements of `xs` and `ys` directly if they are numpy arrays:

```
xs = np.array(xs)
ys = np.array(ys)
point_pairs = np.stack((xs[j], ys[i]), axis=-1)
```

You can also use [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to make the conversion happen under the hood:

```
point_pairs = np.stack((np.take(xs, j), np.take(ys, i)), axis=-1)
```

The remaining elements of `a` are those not covered by the mask:

```
a_points = a[mask]
```

Alternatively:

```
i, j = np.nonzero(a < 1)
point_pairs = np.stack((np.take(xs, j), np.take(ys, i)), axis=-1)
a_points = a[i, j]
```

In this context, you can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as a drop-in alias for `np.nonzero`.

**Notes**

- If you are using numpy, there is rarely a need for lists. Putting `xs = np.array(xs)`, or even just initializing it as `xs = np.arange(1112, 1115)` is faster and easier.
- Numpy arrays should generally be indexed through a single index: `a[0, 1]`, not `a[0][1]`. For your simple case, the behavior just happens to be the same, but it will not be in the general case. `a[0, 1]` is an index into the original array. `a[0]` is a view of the first row of the array, i.e., a separate array object. `a[0][1]` is an index into that new object. You just happened to get lucky that you are getting a view that shares the base memory, so the assignment is visible in `a` itself. This would not be the case if you tried a mask or fancy index, for example.
- On a related note, setting a rectangular swath in an array only requires one line: `a[1:, :-1] = 9`.

I would write your example something like this:

```
a = np.random.random((3, 3))
a[1:, :-1] = 9.0
xs = np.arange(1112, 1115)
ys = np.arange(1109, 1112)

i, j = np.nonzero(a < 1)
point_pairs = np.stack((xs[j], ys[i]), axis=-1)
a_points = a[i, j]
```

Comment: thank you for this answer! the `np.mask` part is working and is much much faster on larger instances. however the `np.stack` line is giving me `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: @notmenotme. Right. That's because `xs` and `ys` are not numpy arrays. My fault. Fixed

Comment: @notmenotme. I've added some notes at the end to help improve your code.